# How to change text string to date to upload into database

Tags: python, sql, excel

I get a data export, and for the date field they all come in as a string like: "1 day ending 01-11-2021".
I want to be able to load these into a database without a lot of manual work changing the dates.

Any advice?

Comment: Perhaps you can find a solution here - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5Dconvert+string+to+date

Comment: Please don't spam unrelated tags.

Comment: Advice: see if the export can be cleaned up during export.  Otherwise, you will have a lot of work converting the data.  It is simpler to solve the problem before it gets to you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to capture the part of string with the date:

```
from datetime import datetime
import re

date_string = "1 day ending 01-11-2021"

#Use regex to find a date-like pattern
match = re.search(r'\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}', date_string)

#Now save the matched string as a datetime object
date = datetime.strptime(match.group(), '%d-%m-%Y').date()
```

This operation can of course be applied to something like a Pandas DataFrame column-wise. Python uses [strftime routines for generating DateTime objects](https://strftime.org/).

[Documentation for strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)